# Si "des" es negación, ¿"desnudo" sería ir vestido?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, prefijos, negación

Al igual que *deshabilitar*, *desinformación*, el prefijo "des-" implica negación. Pero *desnudez*, o *desnudo* significa ir nudo y no lo contrario. ¿Por qué?

Comment: Creo que en este caso des no es prefijo sino parte de la propia palabra.

Comment: El prefijo `des` no siempre indica negación, sino que a veces indica afirmación o exceso. Ejemplos: despavorido, deslenguado.

Answer (score 8):

El significado actual de *desnudo* está influenciado por el significado de *desnudar*, el cual a su vez viene del latín *denudare*, donde la preposición *de-* solo tiene un valor de refuerzo.
Ese *denudar* evolucionó en *desnudar* por influencia de la preposición *des-* que, como bien indicas, se asocia a negación, a ausencia, a quitar algo (en este caso, la ropa); pareciendo, en el habla común, más lógico que la palabra para "quitar la ropa" comenzase por *des-*.

Explicación sacada de [aquí](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?desnudar).

Comment: Según parece *dē-* en latín en este caso tenía el valor de "desde, a partir de" (en sentido de apartamiento). De ahí que reforzara la idea de "quitar la ropa, apartar lo que cubre".

Comment: @pablodf76 El problema es que _nudus_ no significa "ropa" sino "desnudo". Entonces el prefijo _des-_ signifique lo que signifique, no aporta nada.

Comment: @Rodrigo Lo mío no fue una réplica, sino un agregado.

Answer (score 6):

Para complementar la respuesta de @walen, que es la correcta:

El prefijo **de-** existía en latín siglos antes de que se separara el español. Tenía significados diferentes de acuerdo con qué tipo de palabra se combinaba (sustantivo, verbo, etc.), pero para resumir eran los siguientes:

- "**Ir hacia abajo**". De ahí vienen *decaer*, *deducir* (originalmente "ir     de arriba a abajo"), *deportar* (originalmente "traer hacia abajo"),
  *decapitar*, *derribar*, *derrumbar*, *defenestrar*, *desmontar*, *descargar*.
- "**Privación**". Probablemente una derivación del significado anterior,
  como notarás con varios ejemplos de esa lista (*decapitar* podría venir de "caerse la cabeza" o "privado de cabeza"). De aquí deriva el significado
  español "negación" que todos conocemos, y que hace la diferencia típica
  entre *informado* y *desinformado*.
- "**Marcar una separación**", como en *delimitar, demarcar, definir* y *determinar*.
- "**Enfasis**". De donde derivan por ejemplo *demostrar* ("más que sólo mostrar") y *describir*.

Entonces no creas que en todas las palabras españolas que comenzan con de- y en las que se puede identificar prefijo + palabra-base, ese "de" signifique "sin" o "no".